# CanCanCan permissions for has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, cancan

I have has_and_belongs_to_many association between User and Client. Table clients_users has got indexes for User and Client.
My models are:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clients
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  resourcify
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

My controllers are:

```
class Admin::ClientsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
end

class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
end
```

I need something like this in my ability.rb

```
user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

can :read, :all
can :manage, Client, :clients_users => { :user_id => user.id }
```

So I could manage client only when in clients_users table is a record with user_id and id of this client. How do I make it work?

Comment: `can :manage, Client do |p|
           c.clients_users.user_id == user.id
        end`, Something like this should help

Comment: Should be `|c|` instead of `|p|`, but it still wouldn't work (more at accepted answer). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when you use `has_and_belongs_to_many` then you don't have access to the join model, simply because there's no join model, if you want to access that then you need to do `has_many :through` instead.

But in your case you don't really need to access the join model, because `Client` has a `users` attribute, and `User` has a `clients` attribute, so why not just use that instead:

I think something like this should work

```
can :manage, Client, id: user.clients.pluck(:id)
```